# Printable string interpolation not working

Tags: swift, enumeration, string-interpolation

Given the following test code, why aren't the string interpolations \(t1) and \(t2) working?  Renaming `description` causes the compiler to fail with "Type 'Test' does not conform to protocol 'Printable'" and `description` obviously works given the second println of each test.

```
enum Test: Printable {
    case A
    case B(Int)

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .A:
            return ".A"
        case let .B(value):
            return ".B: value = \(value)"
        }
    }
}

let t1 = Test.A
let t2 = Test.B(-100)

println("t1 = \(t1)")       // prints "t1 = (Enum Value)"
println(t1.description)     // prints ".A"

println("t2 = \(t2)")       // prints "t2 = (Enum Value)"
println(t2.description)     // prints ".B: value = -100"
```

Comment: What answers do you want printed?  Then we can help you with code.

Comment: This is known issue of playground. Same code works fine in a Swift project. Work around for now is to use **println("t1 = \(t1.description)")**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that enums being printed as `(Enum Value)` is a known bug in Swift version 1.0 (swift-600.0.51.3). It will be fixed in a future release.

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug report? Seems to be unfixed in v1.1 also.

Comment: Still not fixed as of today. How long can such a simple thing take?

Comment: String interpolation of enumerations is now fixed as of Xcode 6.3 version 6D570.